# Find $\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{(a^x-1)^3}{\sin(x\log a)\log(1+x^2\log a^2)}$

Tags: limits, limits-without-lhopital

> If $$f(x)= \frac{(a^x-1)^3}{\sin(x\log a)\log(1+x^2\log a^2)}$$ is continuous at $x=0$ then find $f(0)$

$$
f(0)=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{(a^x-1)^3}{\sin(x\log a)\log(1+x^2\log a^2)}\\
=\lim_{x\to0}\big[\frac{a^x-1}{x}\big]^3.\frac{x\log a}{\sin(x\log a)}.\frac{x^2}{\log a.\log(1+x^2\log a^2)}\\
=(\log a)^3.1.\lim_{x\to0}\frac{x^2}{\log a.\log(1+x^2\log a^2)}\\
=(\log a)^2.1.\lim_{x\to0}\frac{x^2}{\log(1+x^2\log a^2)}=?
$$

Can I use the fact that $\log(1+x)=x-x2/2+x^3/3-....$  but is it not for $-1<x\leq1$ ?

Comment: Does $\log a^2$ stand for $\log (a^2)$ or $(\log a)^2=\log^2a$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use that

$$\frac{(a^x-1)^3}{\sin(x\log a)\log(1+x^2\log (a^2))}=\frac{(a^x-1)^3}{x^3}\frac{x^3}{\sin(x\log a)\log(1+x^2\log (a^2))}$$

and by standard limits

$$\frac{(a^x-1)^3}{x^3} \to \log^3 a$$

$$\frac{x^3}{\sin(x\log a)\log(1+x^2\log (a^2))}=\frac{x\log a}{\sin(x\log a)}\frac{x^2\log (a^2)}{\log(1+x^2\log (a^2))}\frac1{2\log^2 a} \to \frac1{2\log^2 a}$$

---

**Edit**

Yes we can also use the series expansion since $x^2\log^2 a \to 0$ and therefore eventually $0<x^2\log (a^2)<1$.

Comment: please check I have edited OP. log(1+x) can be expressed as a series for $|x|<1$ right ?

Comment: @ss1729 Yes we can also use series exapansion but in this case standard limits suffice.

Comment: it is actually $\log a^2=2\log a$. So final solution should be $\log\sqrt a$

Comment: @ss1729 Ok then I fix that!

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** Use the fact that $\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\ln(x+1)}{x}=1$.

Answer (score 0):

Using series expansions and $o$-notation you get for $x\to 0$:

$$\frac{(a^x-1)^3}{\sin(x\log a)\log(1+x^2\log a^2)} = \frac{(e^{x\log a}-1)^3}{(x\log a +o(x))(2x^2\log a+ o(x^3))}$$
$$= \frac{(x\log a+o(x))^3}{2x^3\log^2 a+ o(x^3)} = \frac{x^3\log^3 a+o(x^3)}{2x^3\log^2 a+ o(x^3)}$$
$$=\frac{\log^3 a+o(1)}{2\log^2 a+ o(1)} \stackrel{x\to 0}{\longrightarrow}\frac{\log a}{2}$$

Comment: We have that $\log(1+x^2\log^2 a)=x^2\log^2 a +o(x^3)$

Comment: @user : Yes. But the OP writes $\log a^2$ which I interpret as $2\log a$ instead of $\log^2 a$. Maybe the OP should clarify what he/she means. I know that people interpret this differently.

Comment: Ah ok! We can ask about that.

Comment: $\log a^2=2\log a$